# Are the views of Ibn Sina on religion in line with the teachings of Quran?

Tags: sunni, religion

Ibn Sina or Avicenna is one of the greatest Muslim philosophers that left indelible impressions on the Western Philosophy. Not only that Avicenna had contributed immensely to the field of medicine, which continues to benefit the field of modern medicine. Although he comes from today's Uzbekistan, which is part of Central Asia, he is generally considered to be a great scholar of the Persian world.

My question is mainly to the Sunni Muslims. Whether ibn Sina's [Avicenna] religious views are compatible with the Quranic teachings or not. Which ones agree and which ones do not with the teachings of the Quran? why?

Comment: Most Sunnis would consider Ibn Sina extremely heretical if not outside the fold of Islam entirely. Al-Ghazali wrote an entire refutation of Ibn Sina's beliefs named "Incoherence of the Philosophers" with the word "philosophers" referring to Ibn Sina and other people in his school

Comment: Considering Ibn Sina "one of the greatest Muslim philosophers" is probably a largely orientalist viewpoint. Ibn Sina may have had the most effect to the West, so automatically he's the greatest Muslim philosopher since greatness is measured by value to the West.

Comment: @TheZ hm... as far as I know both ibn Rushd (the grandson) and al-Ghazly had more influence on western philosophy, ibn Sina's influence is more in medicine. Further the views of earlier philosophers such as ibn Sina, al-Kindi, al-Farabi are not at all in accordance to Islam, as they are based on Greek philosophy.Further ibn Sina was a Shi'ite therefore his views can hardly be conform to the sunni view.